# How does a transaction log backup deal with active log?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

What happens to the log records that maintain any open uncommitted transactions when a transaction log backup starts? Will these records also be included in the log backup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, active transactions are included in transaction log backups and this is how the database restore `WITH NORECOVERY` option works.

I think it's also important to understand how database restore operations and options work with SQL Server and that too will help you get a better understanding of some of this.

---

### Quoted explanations and some key points to help clarify further

> [**1. Transaction Log Backup**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/8/sql-server-transaction-log-backups/)
>
> ***A transaction log backup*** allows you to backup the *active part of the
> transaction log*.  So after you issue a "Full" or "Differential" backup
> the transaction log backup will have any transactions that were
> created after those other backups completed.  After the transaction
> log backup is issued, the space within the transaction log can be
> reused for other processes.  If a transaction log backup is not taken,
> the transaction log will continue to grow.
>
> ---
>
> [**2. Log Backup Chain**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.sqlbackup.aspx)
>
> ***A log backup chain*** is an unbroken series of log backups that contain
> all the transaction log records necessary to recover a database to a
> point in time. A chain starts with a full database backup, and
> continues until something breaks the chain, thus preventing more log
> backups being taken until another full (or differential) backup is
> taken.
>
> ---
>
> [**3. Truncating the Transaction Log**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173551(v=sql.80).aspx)
>
> When SQL Server finishes backing up the transaction log, it
> automatically ***truncates the inactive portion of the transaction log***.
> This inactive portion contains completed transactions and so is no
> longer used during the recovery process. Conversely, the active
> portion of the transaction log contains transactions that are still
> running and have not yet completed. SQL Server reuses this truncated,
> inactive space in the transaction log instead of allowing the
> transaction log to continue to grow and use more space.

---

### Additional Reading

- [Understanding How Restore and Recovery of Backups Work in SQL
  Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191455(v=sql.105).aspx)